# displaying the list items one after the other in rows and columns

Tags: html, css

I want to display the items in html as below:
1 4  7
2  5  8
3  6
I tried using the following code:

this displays all the items in one column. It should be displayed in 3 rows.
HTML code

```css
#limheight {
    height: 300px; /*your fixed height*/
    -webkit-column-count: 3;
    -moz-column-count: 3;
    column-count: 3; /* in those rules is just placeholder -- can be anything*/
    }
    #limheight li {
    display: inline-block; /*necessary*/
    }
```

```html
<ul id = "limheight">
     <li>
    <span class="oj-typography-body-xs oj-text-color-secondary">"1"</span><br>
    <span class="oj-typography-body-xs oj-text-color-secondary">"2"</span><br>
    <span class="oj-typography-body-xs oj-text-color-secondary">"3"</span><br>
    <span class="oj-typography-body-xs oj-text-color-secondary">"4"</span><br>
    <span class="oj-typography-body-xs oj-text-color-secondary">"5"</span><br>
    </li>

</ul>
            <li>
```

Comment: pleas add html code also ..

Comment: <ul id = "limheight">
            <li>
                <oj-list-item-layout>
                 
                  <span class="oj-typography-body-xs oj-text-color-secondary">"1"</span><br>

Comment: change #limheight to #limheight li ..

Comment: still not working

Comment: what is not working ?

Comment: use grid layout .. check the ans ..

Answer (score 1):

```css
.grid-container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: auto auto auto;
  background-color: #2196F3;
  padding: 10px;
}
.grid-item {
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8);
  border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
  padding: 20px;
  font-size: 30px;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid-container">
  <div class="grid-item">1</div>
  <div class="grid-item">2</div>
  <div class="grid-item">3</div>  
  <div class="grid-item">4</div>
  <div class="grid-item">5</div>
  <div class="grid-item">6</div>  
  <div class="grid-item">7</div>
  <div class="grid-item">8</div>
  <div class="grid-item">9</div>  
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```css
#limheight {
height: 300px; /*your fixed height*/
}
#limheight li {
display: flex;
flex-wrap: wrap;
}

ul {
  width: 100%;
}
span {
  flex: 0 0 33.33%;
}
```

```html
<ul id = "limheight">
 <li>
<span class="oj-typography-body-xs oj-text-color-secondary">"1"</span>
<span class="oj-typography-body-xs oj-text-color-secondary">"2"</span>
<span class="oj-typography-body-xs oj-text-color-secondary">"3"</span>
<span class="oj-typography-body-xs oj-text-color-secondary">"4"</span>
<span class="oj-typography-body-xs oj-text-color-secondary">"5"</span>
<span class="oj-typography-body-xs oj-text-color-secondary">"6"</span>
</li>
</ul>
```

You can make span's height to "300px", if you want their height "300px";